# .Net core 3.1 run methods in parallel

Tags: c#, .net

I want to achieve the following:

```
public AddItem()
{
  //Code goes here
  db.Items.Add(item);
  db.Savechanges();
}

public AddLog()
{
  //Code goes here
  db.Logs.Add(log);
  db.Savechanges();
}

public Main()
{
  if(AddItem() is success)
  // I NEED TO RUN ADD LOGS BUT WITHOUT WAITING, I need it to run in the background.
  Return True;
}
```

How can i do this? its not working with async functions, since the context will be disposed. I dont want to wait for it, just return the API and keep it adding in the database in background

Comment: what language is that?

Comment: Looks like you are confusing asynchronous with concurrency. You don't want asynchronous, you want to concurrently add items to the Log. It looks like you are using Entity Framework which does not support concurrency wrt DbContext. The answer of course is to scope the DbContext to the method, as opposed to the object.

Comment: im using .net core, so the DBContext is scoped. can you clarify more on how can i do that ?

Comment: You question states that it doesn't work with async functions because the context will be disposed. That means you're sharing the context across tasks/threads. What @Aron meant was that you need to construct a new context inside AddLog that it manages itself.

Comment: You are using dotnet core, that does not imply anything about scoping. It sounds like you are using Dependency Injection (which is entirely optional). For you to scope the instance of a transient to a method, you need to either use `IServiceProvider` or `ActivatorUtilities` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#constructor-injection-behavior.